# palm webOS MailService parameter passing problem

Tags: webos

i am developing an application in palm webOS. In that application i have to use the MailService to send mail directly without opening any of the email or compose scenes. For that i have to pass params. But i don't know how to pass the params and what params i have to pass to tha MailService.

```
params.to ="mailId@abc.com";
params.subject = "subj";
params.msg = "message";
this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.mail.MailService', {
        method: 'messageSend',
        parameters: params,
        onSuccess: this.messageSentCallback,
        onError: this.messageErrorCallback          
    });
```

But i am getting error of " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'to' of undefined,"
can you help me to resolve this problem please.

ThanQ for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a basic Javascript error.  Did you put a line like "var params = {};" first to declare the params variable as an empty object?

Do note -- sending email using the service requires that your app access the private system bus as a com.palm.* application.  This means you won't be able to distribute via the App Catalog.

Comment: if i am add the statement of declaration like 

var params = {};

now i am getting the error like

"Error: Error: service request: com.palm.mail.MailService is not running"

Actually for this messageSend method how many params i have to send and what they are?

Comment: The problem you're seeing is that the mail service isn't running, so there's no process on the other end to actually get your request.  You really need to just use a cross-app launch and let the user confirm the email -- that's the sane way to do this.